# How do I hide a command in the palette menu from my extension in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building a VS Code extension starting from [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world) page. Now I want to hide in the palette menu the command `extension.timerStart` after I run it. I have read [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) page, didn't helped. I have the code bellow for package.json. How do I make the `varFromMyExtension===false` part work?

```
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "extension.timerStart",
        "title": "Timer Start"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "commandPalette": [
        {
          "command": "extension.timerStart",
          "when": "varFromMyExtension===false"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code extension: Hide commands from command palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270915/vs-code-extension-hide-commands-from-command-palette)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to access variables from your extension directly in a `when` clause. However you can access any configuration of the `settings.json`.

From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) (at the bottom of the chapter):

> **Note:** You can use any user or workspace setting that evaluates to a boolean here with the prefix `"config."`.

So when your extension contributes a `boolean` [configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesconfiguration) called `varFromMyExtension` you should be able to use it in the `when` clause. This configuration then can be [manipulated programmatically](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration), too.

So your `package.json` would probably contain something like this (not tested):

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "extension.timerStart",
            "title": "Timer Start"
        }
    ],
    "menus": {
        "commandPalette": [
            {
                "command": "extension.timerStart",
                "when": "!config.myextension.varFromMyExtension"
            }
        ]
    },
    "configuration": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Indicates whether ...",
        "properties": {
            "myextension.varFromMyExtension": {
                "title": "My title.",
                "description": "My description",
                "type": "boolean",
                "default": false,
                "pattern": "(true|false)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But bare in mind that the **user can see and edit this setting**, too.