# How to prevent commands from being displayed if the extension is not active?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension and I'm providing a custom command, declare in the `package.json` as:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "myext.doSomething",
        "title": "Do something"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm am then registering it in the extension, when it activates:

```
commands.registerCommand("myext.doSomething", () => console.log("hi"))
```

This works, but the `Do Something` command is present in the command palette even if the extension is not active.

This means that if the user selects the command when the extension is not active, an error along the lines of

> command `myext.doSomething` not found

Is there a way to prevent custom commands to be displayed in the command palette unless the extension has been activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of not showing your command when the extension is not active, you can just add it to the [`activationEvents`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/activation-events#_activationeventsoncommand) like this in your `package.json`. In your case:

```json
{
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:myext.doSomething"
    ]
}
```

This will run the exported `activate` function of your extension before the command is invoked.

Also the [`when`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) keyword could be an option for you. I answered a similar question on that topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687341/how-do-i-hide-a-command-in-the-palette-menu-from-my-extension-in-vs-code/51693238#51693238).

**Edit**:
You can control a command's visibility in the command pallette by additionally contributing a contextual menu ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_context-specific-visibility-of-command-palette-menu-items)). Then you can for instance only display the command when the editor's file has a specific language id.
Example:

```json
{
    "menus": {
        "commandPalette": [
            {
                "command": "myext.doSomething",
                "when": "editorLangId==scala"
            }
        ]
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I don't want to launch my extension when the command is run. The extension makes sense only when the current activation events fire up, so it would lack the context for running the command properly. Also the `when` keyword only works for contextual menus, not for commands.

Comment: Just found [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_context-specific-visibility-of-command-palette-menu-items). It shows how you can control the command's visibility with the `when` keyword. So the trick is to add a contextual menu to the command pallette. I do not know if this helps you when your extension was not activated yet. However it is maybe worth a try.

Comment: Thank you! That indeed works and I'm able to scope the commands to the desired `editorLangId`. If you include that explanation in your answer I'll mark it as accepted!