# VS Code extension: Hide commands from command palette

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

**Background:**

I'm currently working on a simple VS Code extension that will provide dynamically set [command variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables) to my build & debug tasks. The plan is to have a series of attributes that will be accessible in launch.json, etc. through the `"${command:extension.myCommand}"` syntax.

Registering commands like this is as simple as adding an entry to the package.json file, e.g.:

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "extension.myCommand",
            "title": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

and implementing the corresponding commands in my main extension file:

```js
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.myCommand', () => {
    return "dynvar";
});
context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```

**The Problem**:

Unfortunately these commands now also appear in the command palette, and as they don't have any interactive use that's quite annoying.

**Question:**

Is there any way I can hide commands contributed through extensions from VS Code's command palette?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't need to associate an `"icon"` or a `"title"` with your command, you can simply omit it from `"commands"` - commands that are not listed there can still be called, as long as they have been registered via `vscode.commands`.

Otherwise, you can use the following trick to hide it from the command palette:

```json
"contributes": {
    "menus": {
        "commandPalette": [
            {
                "command": "extension.myCommand",
                "when": "false"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! FWIW, it seems like I can also just leave the `contributes` section blank and the commands will still be callable through command variables. However, that might be a hack rather than the proper way to do things, so I'm marking this as the canonical answer.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily a hack, you indeed don't need to register a command in `package.json` to be able to call it. `"when": "false"` is mainly useful for commands that are used in the UI / for buttons, but shouldn't show up in the command palette. In that case you would want / have to set `"title"` and `"icon"` as well. I'll update my answer with that info.

Comment: I get a `Menu item references a command \`<command name>\` which is not defined in the 'commands' section` error when I try to reference a command from a `"menus":` item that I registered in JS/TS with `registerCommand`/`registerTextEditorCommand` but haven't added to `"commands":` in package.json.

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet illustrates how to hide a command registered as 'extension.myHiddenCommand':

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
    {
        "command": "extension.myHiddenCommand",
        "title": "Compile folder"
    }],
    "menus": {
        "commandPalette": [
        {
            "command": "extension.myHiddenCommand",
            "when": "false"
        }]
    }
}
```